# How do you use different images for normal vs active states on muse for on click tabbed panel tabs?

Tags: adobe, muse, creative-cloud, adobe-cc

I am a beginner level on Adobe's Muse platform and I am trying to use 2 different images on the same tab for a tabbed panel. I want to use the grey version when it is on the normal state vs using the blue version when it is on the active state.

Keep in mind I do not want this with a roll-over, I want this on click.

Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the right menu you can see the states when you click the Image.
And you can choose the Image you want to show in the active(focused) state on the right top corner(background).So,when the image is clicked it changes the background.